# Отправка формы по Enter, React, Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Есть функция orderButtonOnClick, которая используя значения props формирует заказ. Она нормально работает, если происходит клик по кнопке. Но нужно также отправлять заказ по нажатию клавиши Enter. И тут происходит неприятное - значения props берутся такие, как при первом ренедеринге. Те. не происходит обновления address. В отладчике изменения состояния видны. Не понимаю, в чем причина?

```
const ContactDetailsForm = props => {
    const address = props.state.address;
    const [contactDetails, setContactDetails] = useState([
        {
            name: 'address',
            value: address,
            title: 'Address'
        }
    ]);

    const [activeElement, setActiveElement] = useState('contact-details-form');

    useEffect(() => {
        setContactDetails([
            {
                name: 'address',
                value: address,
                title: 'Address'
            }
        ]);
    }, [address]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const onKeyDown = e => {
            if(e.keyCode === 13) {
                orderButtonOnClick();
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
        };
    }, []);

    const changeInputValueHandler = e => {
        const {name, value} = e.target;
        let newContactDetails = [...contactDetails];
        newContactDetails.map(input => {
           if(input.name === name)
               input.value = value;
            return input
        });
        setContactDetails(newContactDetails);
        dispatch(changeInputValue({name,value}));
    };

    const orderButtonOnClick = () => {
        const newOrder = {
            address
        };
        console.log(address);
        dispatch(insertOrder(newOrder));
        }
    };

    const dispatch = props.dispatch;
    return(
        <section>
                   <form>
                       {contactDetails.map(input => {
                               return <FormInput key={input.name}
                                                 title={input.title}
                                                 name={input.name}
                                                 value={input.value}
                                                 changeInputValue={changeInputValueHandler}/>
                           }
                       )}
                   </form>
                   <button onClick={orderButtonOnClick}>Order</button>
          
        </section>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте useRef.

Там где объявляется address, замените на:

```
const address = useRef();
address.current = props.state.address;
```

И в самом верху там где импортируется реакт, не забудьте `useRef` добавить:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
```

Остальной код оставьте как есть.

[Подробнее о хуке useRef и принципах его работы (смотреть видео)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Yy6MDsF-Tg)

Comment: Это помогло. Но я не понимаю в чем заключалась проблема.

Comment: @Tea проблема была в том, что у вас функция обрабатывала не текущее значение, а первое, которое попало в функцию. Это особенность функциональных компонентов, в отличии от классовых. А useRef создаёт как бы отсылку на текущее значение, и может использоваться в любом месте, ссылаясь на то значение которое в данный момент актуально.

Comment: Все понятно! Спасибо!